# Is it true that tensorflow ONLY work on python3.5.2?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Im a windows 10 user and this is my version of python at the moment

```
Python 3.6.3 (v3.6.3:2c5fed8, Oct  3 2017, 18:11:49) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

and when i try to install tensorflow with pip this pop up

```
tensorflow_gpu-0.12.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I ve looking on the internet which suggest that tensorflow now only work on python 3.5.2. Is it true? if not then how do i bypass that error?

Answer (score 3):

TensorFlow only supports Python 3.5 64-bit as of now. Support for Python 3.6 is a work in progress and you can track it [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6999) as well as chime in the discussion.

The only alternative to use Python 3.6 with TensorFlow on Windows currently is building TF from source.

If you don't want to uninstall your Anaconda distribution for Python 3.6 and install a previous release you can create a conda environment for Python=3.5 as in: 
conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
pip install tensorflow-gpu

Also one more alternative
If you are using anaconda distribution, you can do the following to use python 3.5 on the new environnement "tensorflow":

conda create --name tensorflow python=3.5
activate tensorflow
conda install jupyter
conda install scipy
pip install tensorflow

## or

## pip install tensorflow-gpu

It is important to add python=3.5 at the end of the first line, because it will install Python 3.5.

Comment: Thank you very much for you respond, i dont use Anaconda and i have python 3.6.x on my computer now, and even if i try to install the 3.5.2 it still  on python 3.6.x should i delete the python36 and download python again?

Comment: Im sorry but do you mean that `pip install tensorflow-gpu python=3.5`because it return `Invalid requirement: 'python=3.5'`

Comment: Brilliant!. Working like a charm. Thanks Rajasekhar

Comment: I think the answer it not up to date anymore as there is `tensorflow-gpu` for python 3.6 on window 10

Comment: Hi, what about Python 2? Does Tensorflow still support Python 2.7 ? Thank you very much

Comment: @DangManhTruong You should not use Python 2 anymore.

Comment: @DangManhTruong No it doesn't.

Comment: @gerrit I still remember the Unicode issue ... And the criticism from the Learn python the hard way guy

Comment: @DangManhTruong With unicode it's Python 2 that has problems, not Python 3.